# Bipolar and paintings

Tags: psychology, bipolar-disorder

A year ago or so I discovered a study where the power spectrum of paintings were compared among various painters from the past and present day. Among the present day painters there were bipolar, etc. people. These present day painter's paintings were then compared with painters such as Van Gogh.

These finding were used to suggest a method to "prove" that painters, like Van Gogh, were bipolar or had some other mental illness.

I thought this was interesting but have long since been unable to find this again for further review. Does anyone know of this particular study,? If so could you please reference it.

Comment: Pulled an hour or so search for this study using all the cool terms I could think of, and I got no joy. There is plenty on the [illness of Van Gogh](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&q=van+gogh+bipolar&btnG=&as_sdt=1%2C6&as_sdtp=&oq=van+go), though.

Comment: It's as if it was fake and they pulled it from the internet. I've searched again and again for various keywords or combinations thereof trying to find it, with no such luck. Thank you for your efforts. Maybe someone else will discover it again, and know of this post.

Comment: Yes: wish you the best in your search, and sorry there wasn't an instant answer for you!